# Is the jQuery plugin authoring tutorial obsolete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Is the jQuery plugin authoring tutorial located [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) obsolete?  I mean, I am sure it still works, but are there better, more recent standards accepted to author plugins?  What about creating [Stateful jQuery plugins using jQuery UI’s widget factory](http://blog.petersendidit.com/post/stateful-jquery-plugins-with-jquery-uis-widget-factory/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks up-to-date to me, including talking about the `data` function which is fairly recent. One of the great things about jQuery's plug-in mechanism is how bare-bones it is. Barriers to entry are virtually nil, making dashing off and sharing a quick plug-in trivially easy.

The widget factory article you refer to describes one framework for making more complex plug-ins, but it doesn't invalidate or outdate the main article, and it's just one approach to doing it (and not *necessarily* the best one, but let's not get off-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many tutorials how-to-create jQuery plugins, and I think they would update it when needed

Comment: There are loads of outdated or plain incorrect tutorials and howto floating around on the internet and I don't see why jQuery would be any different in that respect.

Comment: @awoodland: I was talking about jQuery's documentation one